# Angular - Route two different paths to different components within the same lazy-loaded submodule

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-routing

I've two paths
/a and /b

In my parent module, I route them to the same child module:

```js
// app-routing.moudle.ts
  {
    path: 'a',
    loadChildren: () => import('./m-child/m-child.module').then(m => m.ChildModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'b',
    loadChildren: () => import('./m-child/m-child.module').then(m => m.ChildModule),
  },
```

and in child module, I want to route a and b to different components, i.e.

```js
// m-child-routing.module.ts
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: AComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'b',
    component: BComponent
  },
```

I don't want to redefine routes, i.e. I don't want /a/a or /b/b. I want to keep them simple one level: /a and /b, but still loaded through the same lazy-loaded module.

Is it possible to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: I think you're over complicating this and trying to go against how it's supposed to work. I'd recommend to not use a module in the first place and point to a standalone component OR create 2 different modules as you'll be pointing anyway to different components.

Comment: @maxime1992 Thank you so much. I didn't know that standalone components could be lazy loaded! That should work!!

Answer (score 0):

While loading a module via route, you import and load all the children components in the module, which itself contradicts the lazy loading concept u require here, if you only need 'a' component to be loaded for said route `host/a` you can directly add `component: AComponent` in your app-routing.module.ts; and similarly for BComponent. This solution is feasible if you load only the a or b component from app-routing and not along with a main component that loads in the child module under `path:''` within which a and b fall

Comment: these components have their own dependencies. If I directly add ```component: AComponent```, those dependencies will be loaded all at once at the parent level, bloating my application.

Comment: The right way to load your component at `/a` would be to not use a module and import the `AComponent` as standalone component in your routing, or the other way around is to create two modules and load empty path `path:''` and route it to A or B component respectively, Hope this helps. The OG comment from maxime1992 is the simple way